# sqlalchemy: Controlling columns selected from query

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm having a bit of an issue with sqlalchemy. I'm creating a query like:

```
db.session.query(Case.court_id).filter(
        Case.last_updated.between(start, end)).filter(
                (Case.last_scraped_by != "RSS") | 
                (Case.last_scraped_by.is_(None))).order_by(Case.last_updated.desc()).distinct()
```

Which results in the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT `case`.court_id AS case_court_id, `case`.last_updated AS 
case_last_updated FROM `case` WHERE `case`.last_updated BETWEEN %s AND %s 
AND (`case`.last_scraped_by != %s OR `case`.last_scraped_by IS NULL) ORDER BY `case`.last_updated DESC
```

The issue here is I want only distinct `Case.court_id`'s from the database, but due to `Query.order_by` changing the column list I get incorrect results, I've scoured the docs for sqlalchemy but so far have found no way to explicitly control the columns selected. So my question, is what would be the best way to explicitly control the columns selected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this one (moved `distinct` to `select` part):

```
db.session.query(Case.court_id.distinct()).filter(
        Case.last_updated.between(start, end)).filter(
                (Case.last_scraped_by != "RSS") | 
                (Case.last_scraped_by.is_(None))).order_by(Case.last_updated.desc())
```

*However, it might be up to a database engine to allow such constructs.*

Comment: Surprisingly that worked, it made sqlalchemy stop adding the `Case.last_updated` column to the select statement. That'll work for the moment, thanks

Comment: Glad it worked, however I do believe some RDMBSs might complain.